# How to sort month and year in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with month and year column. How can I sort the date and year . Please check the fiddle.

In this case, The date format is "MMMM yyyy". My requirement is for example,

if my date is "August 2016", "September 2015" and "January 2018". Here I want to sort date based on the year. So the result should come like this,
"September 2015","August 2016" and "January 2018".

How can I do this in angularjs.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pvqau4z/184/)

```js
   var app = angular.module('app', [])
       .controller('appController', appController);

   appController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];

   function appController($scope, $window) {

       $scope.title = "date sorting example";

       $scope.sortType = "name";
       $scope.sortReverse = true;

       var dateA = new Date("02/06/2016");
       dateA.setDate(dateA.getDate() + 2);
       var dateB = new Date("07/06/2017");
       dateB.setDate(dateB.getDate() + 4);
       var dateC = new Date("08/06/2016");
       dateC.setDate(dateC.getDate() + 7);
       var dateD = new Date("04/06/2018");
       dateD.setDate(dateD.getDate() + 20);

       $scope.allItems = [{
           date: dateA,
           name: "A"
       }, {
           date: dateB,
           name: "B"
       }, {
           date: dateC,
           name: "C"
       }, {
           date: dateD,
           name: "D"
       }];

   };
```

```html
<div ng-controller="appController">

    <h1>This is my {{title}}</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <td data-ng-click="sortType = name; sortReverse = !sortReverse;">
                Date
            </td>
            <td data-ng-click="sortType = name; sortReverse = !sortReverse;">
                Name
            </td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in allItems">
                <td>{{item.date | date:"MMMM yyyy"}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
var dateA = new Date("02/06/2016");
dateA.setDate(dateA.getDate() + 2);
var dateB = new Date("07/06/2017");
dateB.setDate(dateB.getDate() + 4);
var dateC = new Date("08/06/2016");
dateC.setDate(dateC.getDate() + 7);
var dateD = new Date("04/06/2018");
dateD.setDate(dateD.getDate() + 20);

let allItems = [{date: dateA,name: "A"}, {date: dateB,name: "B"}, {date: dateC,name: "C"}, {date: dateD,name: "D"}];

allItems.sort((a,b) => a.date - b.date);

console.log(allItems);
```